# Modifying member objects inside class c++

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` with a member that is a `std::vector` of pointers to objects of another class `B`. My class returns a `const` pointer to an object at a particular index. Now, if I want to modify the object, what is the best way of doing that?

I can write get/set methods in class `A`, which will eventually use get/set methods of class `B`, but it is a duplication of code. Is it good practice to modify the private members by using the `friend` keyword?

Or, I can make class `A` be a `friend` of class `B`, then it can modify the private members of `B` to avoid duplication of code.

Or, I can remove the `const` on the returned pointer.

```
class B;

class A {
    std::vector<B*> m_list;
public:
    const B* getB(int index) {
        return m_list[index];
    }
};

class B {
private:
    int a;
    float b;
    long c;

    long getC() {
        return C;
    }

    int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    float getB() {
        return b;
    }

    /*
    set_methods
    */
};
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, are you able to produce a code [mcve] to illustrate your question?

Comment: "Is it good practice to modify the private members by using the friend keyword?" - No.

Comment: "I can remove the const on the returned pointer" - this is even worse than "friend".

Comment: It's almost impossible to give a general advice in this way. Such concerns you're having only make sense relative to concrete use cases.

Comment: it is not clear from your class who owns the instances, u should use a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: "Or, I can remove the const on the returned pointer." you cannot modify an object through a const pointer, so removing `const` is necessitated. "Or, I can make class `A` be a friend of class `B`, then it can modify the private members of `B` to avoid duplication of code." yeah, if you only want to be able to modify members from `A` then that's fine, and not really concretely bad practice. Your real intention is still not clear, but honestly, I imagine you're overthinking and getting confused. I could be wrong but I reckon, `B` s members shouldn't be `private` at all, but `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constness and friendship are two completely different and unrelated things.

It doesn't matter if `A` is a friend of `B` or not.  That is simply a design choice on your part whether you want to encapsulate access to the `B` members inside of `A`, or if you want to allow the caller to access `B` getters/setters directly.

As far as modifying an object is concerned, any getters should be declared as `const` so they can be called on `const` and non-`const` objects alike (since they don't modify the object they are reading from), but if you want to be able to *modify* the members of an object then you must access the object via a non-`const` pointer (or non-`const` reference):

```
class B;

class A {
private:
    std::vector<B*> m_list;

public:
    // this can be called on a non-const A, and
    // the B members can be read and modified...
    B* getB(int index) {
        return m_list[index];
    }

    // this can be called only on a const A, and
    // the B members can be read but not modified...
    const B* getB(int index) const {
        return m_list[index];
    }

    /* optional:

    int getB_A(int index) const {
        return getB(index)->getA();
    }

    float getB_B(int index) const {
        return getB(index)->getB();
    }

    long getC(int index) const {
        return getB(index)->getC();
    }

    void setB_A(int index, int value) {
        getB(index)->setA(value);
    }

    void setB_B(int index, float value) {
        getB(index)->setB(value);
    }

    void setB_C(int index, long value) {
        getB(index)->setC(value);
    }

    */
};

class B {
private:
    int a;
    float b;
    long c;

public:
    int getA() const {
        return a;
    }

    float getB() const {
        return b;
    }

    long getC() const {
        return c;
    }

    void setA(int value) {
        a = value;
    }

    void setB(float value) {
        b = value;
    }

    void setC(long val) {
        c = val;
    }
};
```

Or:

```
class B;

class A {
private:
    std::vector<B*> m_list;

public:
    // this can be called on a non-const A, and
    // the B members can be read and modified...
    B* getB(int index) {
        return m_list[index];
    }

    // this can be called only on a const A, and
    // the B members can be read but not modified...
    const B* getB(int index) const {
        return m_list[index];
    }

    int getB_A(int index) const {
        return getB(index)->a;
    }

    float getB_B(int index) const {
        return getB(index)->b;
    }

    long getC(int index) const {
        return getB(index)->c;
    }

    void setB_A(int index, int value) {
        getB(index)->a = value;
    }

    void setB_B(int index, float value) {
        getB(index)->b = value;
    }

    void setB_C(int index, long value) {
        getB(index)->c = value;
    }
};

class B {
private:
    int a;
    float b;
    long c;

    friend class A;
};
```